# AWS DMS Migration - Will this scenario work? (Migrate from Non-Encrypted MYSQL/POSTGRES to an Encrypted MYSQL/POSTGRES)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-migration

I have a situation where I have two databases, one MYSQL and one POSTGRES SQL. I needed  both to be encrypted - currently they are not.
I understand I can create a snapshrot, copy the snapshot with my CMK and restore it to create an encrypted database.

But I also require both to be updated with the source so I can cutover seamlessly. DMS works for me  and I can use CDC.

**What  I'm unsure of is  can DMS migrate from an UNENCRYPTED source to an ENCRYPTED  Target?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DMS is just creating regular database connections to the RDS databases. The encryption happens on the backend, at the storage level. When DMS runs SELECTs against your unencrypted DB, and then runs INSERTs against your encrypted DB, it's just a regular client of those databases, and it won't matter at all that one of those servers happens to have an encrypted file system.

If this is so important that you have to have a seamless cutover, I highly recommend setting up some test migrations first to verify everything works like you expect.

Comment: So its an UNENCRYPTED  Select (at source) vs  an INSERT (at target) + database automatically encrypting each row using  the  KMS Key?

Comment: The database isn't encrypting each row. The operating system is encrypting the files on the hard drive. It's the same mechanism EC2 uses to encrypt EBS volumes. These RDS instances are just EC2 instances with EBS volumes behind the scenes, with Amazon managing the database software that is installed on there for you.